# Angular 2 dynamically load data

Tags: angular, ng2-smart-table, ng2-admin

I browsed around a bit to see if there is a way using which I can render my component with a partially populated object. I am hitting an api where it returns 1000's of records and I was wondering if there was a way using which I can load a table with the data while it is being returned rather than waiting for it to be rendered when all of it is returned.

The reason I am opting for a solution like this is because I am unable to find a proper pagination and filter example for ng2-smart-table where data is partially loaded from the server.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: do you work with a stream based api?

Comment: I have a spring boot project with simple crud repositories.

Comment: You need to implement pagination from server , then we can handle it at client side easily

Comment: Well, I have pagination at server end but I am unable to find the events that should be generated on next page request so that I can make a call to the server. I am using ng2-smart-table on client side.